# Bootstrap 3 portrait custom style col-md

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, portrait

I'm trying to create a custom `col-md` property on Bootstrap 3. What I need it's the same properties like the other predefined styles, e.g:

```
.col-md-2 {
  width: 16.6667%;
}
.col-md-2 {
  float: left;
}
.col-md-2 {
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
```

And I want to create a new one with `width: 20%` but the deal is that when I use one of the predefined bootstrap styles like `col-md-2` and view the page on portrait, it doesn't use the width and float properties (really don't know why, I examined the element with firebug and it's just like the float and width properties were not declared when I view the page on portrait mode), but when i declare the new one and watch it on portrait, it stills uses width and float properties and the element doesn't look responsive.

Comment: Maybe your styles have impact only on some media-query ranges?? When You change your device into portrait mode, styles for lower screen device are being applied

Comment: Have you tried using `!important` to see if it works or not?  If it does not work, you may have either the wrong selector or your selector is placed within the wrong media query.

Comment: thanks @MichalKutra my style properties were only affect some media ranges, i posted a link with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all of you for your quick answers! I found that i need to declare the @media min-width properties like it says on this link:http://www.wearesicc.com/quick-tips-5-column-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap/